# JavaScript Promise.race does not resolve synchronously

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'll be quick. MDN provides the following [example for Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

But that example on their website is a bit misleading, as there is no code that depends on the result of the race. I've adapted the code a bit and it behaves quite weirdly.

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one');
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'two');
});

(async () => {
  let val = 'zero';
  Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then((result) => {
    val = result;
    console.log("Assigned value", val);
  })
  console.log(val);
})();
```

If you run the snippet above, you'll see that the result is `zero`.
I would expect calling `then` on the race would make the execution synchronous, but apparently, that is not the case.
So how do I do that? What do I need to modify in this example for the last log to print "two"?

Comment: `await` the call of the Promise so that the surrounding function stops while waiting for the Promise to finish. Not really anything to do with `Promise.race` in particular - this would be reproducible with a simple `Promise.resolve()` too

Comment: "*there is no code that depends on the result of the race.*" - sure there is, all of the examples at MDN have something like `.then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
  // Both resolve, but promise2 is faster
});`